# Adding Custom Windows Controls on WPF User Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a WinForms User Control (a toolbar) which i would like to add on a WPF user Control, is there any way to do this?

*like i want a WinForms User Control (the toolbar) along with other WPF Controls
(datagrid) on a new WPF User Control*

I saw a couple of samples that show Windows Forms hosted in a WPF Control. But that is not what i want to see.

Comment: You want to use a WPF control in a WinForms application, right?

Comment: By "Windows .NET User Control" do you mean a WinForms UserControl, or a WPF UserControl?

Comment: @Joe White - A win forms User Control.

Comment: @iaimtomisbehave : nope the other way, a windows user control in a WPF user control

Comment: "But that is not what i want to see" Sounds like it's *exactly* what you want to see: hosting WinForms in a WPF parent. Can you explain why those samples don't solve your problem?

Comment: @JoeWhite : yeah i guess that is what i wanted, just understood them in a different way earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to pull off.  There is a handy little thing known as `WindowsFormHost`  all you have to do is declare it in your control's XAML, and nest your forms control inside of it, like so:

```
<UserControl>
...
<Grid>
  <WindowsFormsHost>
    <forms:MyFormsToolbarControl/>
  </WindowsFormHost>
</Grid>

...
```

`WindowsFormHost` lives inside of the normal WPF toolbox so it shouldn't be hard to locate.  Meanwhile there is an example of how to produce the equivalent XAML in code at this location...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my answer to a similar question here:

[WPF hosting a WinForm, Tab Navigation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166476/wpf-hosting-a-winform-tab-navigation-problems/20177125#20177125)

This will also show you how to fix a tabbing issue with windows controls that are sitting inside wpf views.